# Compiling separate SASS files in Angular-CLI

Tags: sass, angular-cli

I need to be able to create and compile separate SASS files in Angular CLI in order to change themes based on the current user.

I had hoped to use a webpack plugin but it seems that CLI doesn't allow you to customize the webpack config file.

Suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: Could you please provide more information about used versions, etc.? That could make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: @Tobonaut Its all the latest  versions, (so angular v4)